# Conversion of Int elements of list not producing chars Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(Args : Array<String>){
  var list = listOf(1,2,3)
  for(x in list){
    print(x.toChar())
  }
}
```

This is just an illustration of the challenge i am facing on some code i am writing that is supposed to add elements to a Char list from some of the  elements of an Int list. the code above is producing the following result. Thank you for the assistance in advance

result :

Comment: Your code produces the characters with unicode codes 0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003. Do you want these, or the equivalent of "1", "2", and "3" respectively?

Comment: What exactly did you expect? Calling `toChar()` on an `Int` will return a `Char` with the Unicode value of the `Int`. The characters with codes 1, 2, 3 are not printable characters.

Comment: Alright thank you, so how may I go about changing a 1 into a '1' for instance in Kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted produces not the chars denoting the digits but the chars with values equal to those `Int`s (i.e. [0x01, 0x02, 0x03](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

If you need to print the ints, then use either `print(x)` or `print("$x")` or `print(x.toString())`.

If you want to get the chars denoting the digits, you can do that as `'0' + x`, given `x` in `0..9`.